# How do I convert mysql query to django model's ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, orm

This is my mysql query.

```
SELECT DeviceUID, Max(LogTime) , count(DeviceUID), Mode
 FROM P2PLog.ConnectResult_Table group by DeviceUID;
```

How do I convert this code to ORM?

I try to this orm. I need to select `Max(LogTime)` as column. How do I do?

```
>>> ct = ConnectresultTable.objects
>>> aaa = ct.values('deviceuid', 'mode').annotate(items=Count('deviceuid'))
>>> print aaa.query
SELECT `ConnectResult_Table`.`DeviceUID`, `ConnectResult_Table`.`Mode`, COUNT(`C
onnectResult_Table`.`DeviceUID`) AS `items` FROM `ConnectResult_Table` GROUP BY
`ConnectResult_Table`.`DeviceUID`, `ConnectResult_Table`.`Mode` ORDER BY NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get answer by myself. Thanks everyone!

```
>>> ct = ConnectresultTable.objects
>>> aaa = p2p_ct.values('deviceuid', 'mode').annotate(items=Count('deviceuid'),
new_status=Max('logtime'))
>>> print aaa.query
SELECT `ConnectResult_Table`.`DeviceUID`, `ConnectResult_Table`.`Mode`, COUNT(`C
onnectResult_Table`.`DeviceUID`) AS `items`, MAX(`ConnectResult_Table`.`LogTime`
) AS `new_status` FROM `ConnectResult_Table` GROUP BY `ConnectResult_Table`.`Dev
iceUID`, `ConnectResult_Table`.`Mode` ORDER BY NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

`$ python manage.py inspectdb`   Run this command!

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py    Save your file using Unix.

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'CENSUS_PERSONS'       ( Create unmanaged modes, managed=false)


$ python manage.py migrate   ( And install this)
```